# longtable spread to multicol

Tags: longtable, multicol

I have a document where one part is pretty long 2-column table (like 200 lines or so). I used `longtable` to ensure that the table would spread across multiple pages, but it took 5 of them to render.

I tried to use `multicol` package to render 3 parts of the table per page, but it didn't work. It used only first column of the multicol

Do you know any working alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "but it took 5 of them to render". Did you use five separate `longtable` environments? If not, what did you do? Please advise.

Comment: 999 times out of 1000 2-column tables can be set as a list which will work much better in multicol but you have given no clues as to what your document looks like, and no example code so hard to offer any suggestions.

Comment: It stretched over 5 A4 pages just by its length. There are too many items in the table.